# How to handle multiple MQTT MSGs received on on_message

Tags: mqtt

My `MQTT` client is `paho mqt` in Python and the broker is `mosquitto`. I am sending multiple messages on one topic at the same time using threads in Python. I want to return an answer corresponding to each message, but I feel `paho mqtt` is single threaded and cant handle simultaneous requests. How can I solve it? I know `MQTT` v5 supports request-response pattern but, `paho mqtt` in Python can't provide it yet.

Comment: What do you mean by _at the same time_ ? The published messages are still handled by the broker in the order they arrive. Please provide code of your subscriber

Comment: I mean when at time X we receive 10 msgs, for instance.